# Не получается сделать push python приложения в Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, push

Пытаюсь сделать push python-приложения в heroku, но каждый раз не выходит с одной и той же ошибкой. Как можно исправить?

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 5.72 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon- 
buildpacks.s3.am
azonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detec
tion-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to projectname.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git'
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Немного поискал и создал Procfile, после некоторого времени наконец сработало.

Comment: @mit как не является? Он сам на свой вопрос ответил.

Comment: Александр, а можно чуть больше подробностей про ответ? Что-то нужно записать в Procfile?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я написал туда `worker: python имяскрипта.py`